# Android SQLite new DB version with one table removed

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my Android application I'm using the SQLite DB with `SQLiteOpenHelper`

I have several DB versions, and I've been doing `onUpgrade()` operations by switching on the old db version, but now I have to remove one of the tables because I'm no longer using it, so should I do something different?

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(tableUserCreate);
        database.execSQL(tableProductsCreate);
        database.execSQL(tablePicturesCreate);
    }


public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
    switch (version_old) {
    case 1:
        database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
        database.execSQL(tablePlacesCreate);
        // Intentional fallthrough, no break;
    case 2:
        database.execSQL(tableProductVideosCreate);
        break;
    }
} // End of onUpgrade
```

Now I want to remove the User table in a new **DB version**. What do I do?

Comment: In case 2, drop the unnecessary table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL for dropping a table:

```
DROP TABLE table_name
```

Or use:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name
```

Comment: there is an SQL command that creates the new table in the DB, and there are constant fields for the table fields, should I leave them there because they are being used in case1?

Comment: So I am first creating it in onCreate, then Im dropping it in the new case in the switch statement?

Comment: Unefficient, but works. You could do an if statement in onCreate to see if the users table needs to be crated!

Comment: @J.K. please accept this as a correct answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

When you change Database_Version it called

> onUpdate(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)

method first, so you have to do all drop or create kind of stuff inside that method. In your case you use Switch case i do same things using if else.
But both work fine in that case.

> if (newVersion == yourNewVersion) {
>
> try {
>
> // Drop older table if existed
>
> db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + YOUR_TABLE_NAME);
>
> // Create tables again IF YOU WANT TO CREATE HERE
>
> } catch (Exception e) {
>            e.printStackTrace();
>
> }